# Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 REST API in Java

Tags: java, office365, daemon, azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

I am trying to build a batch job to access Office 365 Mail API. Up on checking the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) (the concept is very clear), I wasn't able to find a code sample written for Java. I've found [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/releases) but it relies on the java pom file but I would love to use REST API or Graphi API directly if possible.

Can someone point me on how to get started with building a Daemon service to access Office 365 REST API without users login ?

**UPDATE**

I've the following code to get the token using AADL library

```
String tenant="....";
        String authority = "https://login.windows.net/"+tenant+"/oauth2/authorize";
        ExecutorService service=null;
        service= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        try{

            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext= new AuthenticationContext(authority,false,service);
            String certFile="/mycert2.pfx";
            InputStream pkcs12Cert= new SharedFileInputStream(certFile);

            AsymmetricKeyCredential credential=AsymmetricKeyCredential.create("....",pkcs12Cert,"pass");


            Future<AuthenticationResult> future=authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com",credential,null);

            System.out.println("Token Received"+future.get().getAccessToken());
            String token = future.get().getAccessToken();

            HttpGet httpGet = new       HttpGet("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");

            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);


            GraphServices graphServices = new GraphServices();
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;


            //responseEntity = graphServices.getEmails(token); //Throws the same Unauthorized exception 

            HttpClient httpClient= HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
//response contains Unauthorized access 
            HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Here the Unauthorized error from the http.execute method

> HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8, Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5,
>   request-id: 49ca360f-ab4b-42d5-a4b0-9676e4244c21, client-request-id:
>   49ca360f-ab4b-42d5-a4b0-9676e4244c21, x-ms-ags-diagnostic:
>   {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West
>   US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"003","Host":"AGSFE_IN_8","ADSiteName":"WST"}},
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2016 20:43:24 GMT,
>   Content-Length: 244] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 244,Chunked: false]}}
>
> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJxcy76FRUlljRV9tb3RXVkpLSHJ3TEJiZF85cyIsImtpZCI6IlliUkFRUlljRV9tb3RXVkpLSHJ3TEJiZF85cyJ9.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.BKt54345DIfv2WWT4pQ--Nuy-0aHkkht4332r7E4d5mP-EAEKmcQe7y0IPjkYGZTNhyNiG2tVAyb56Gcbessdsfewz_BNoAolTVukxttXc-pFY1_Ol5Adc8T5yio43ixfs88mrVRqZEHsb7c-wjO-otBXocZs8waYXdree83g1JtcnULs7bAGp3VBUhMjuJ2u87363Yq3lfse39_Pt6tRw]

(the token is something similar to this, just changed it to something similar for security)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java walkthrough here (though for a web app using auth code flow): https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/java

There's also this sample that uses client credential flow:

https://github.com/jasonjoh/java-calendar-demo

Comment: I think both use authenticate users with login UI. We are building a background service and this won't work for us but thanks for the help.

Comment: You only need that authentication the first time for an admin to grant consent to the app. You can skip that part after initial consent is given.

Comment: that means, even app credential won't be given without user interaction at least once ? What I thought was, app would be given credential once the setup on Azure side is done. I never thought thought there would be user interaction from the app.

Comment: Only if it is a multitenant scenario. If you register the app in your Office 365 tenant, it is already "consented" for your tenant, and no interaction is required. If you make it multitenant, then you need user interaction for those other tenants (one time).

Comment: Thank you. I was able to authenticate using the certificate and received a token but I wasn't able to get resources ( email and contacts in this case) using the Graph Service. I'll find a work around and may come back here if I've a question. Thank you for your help so far. Btw, we do have paid Azure account for our Enterprise. Do you give support for clients if we create a ticket directly ? Thanks.

Comment: I personally don't work in support, I mainly just help here as I can.

Comment: That is okay. I updated my question. I now couldn't get the resources I need.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I was now able to get things work somehow. After changing the end points to refer to graph.microsoft.com I was able to get users email for now. But when I tried to access their messages using the following end point (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@microsoft.com/Messages) I received 403 forbidden exception. Am I missing something ? This end pint > https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users brought me results though.

Comment: I see you posted another question for this, so I'll respond there just to keep it clearer for other folks :)

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate in the daemon or service apps, we can use **Client Credentials** flow. After we register the app, we would get the **secret**. Then we can use the request below direct to get the app-only access token:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<clientId>
&client_secret=<clientSecret>
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

And to use the Office 365 access token, we can replace the resource with `https://outlook.office.com`. [Here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) is a detail document about calling Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app.

Comment: I was able to get the token but when I use the Graph services to get emails I get 401 (Unauthorized) even though I already gave the applications all permissions needed.

Comment: You can parse the token through [here](https://jwt.io/) to check the detail about the token. What's the **aud** claim in the token and what's the request you were making?

Comment: I have updated my code that throws the Unauthorized exception. Any ideas why ? I am not using the JWT assuming future.get().getAccessToken(); gives me back the access token I have to send either for Graph API or HTTP request.

Comment: FYI, you cant use client secret for Daemon services. You must use a certificate

Comment: The code you request the token for the resource **https://outlook.office365.com**, however you were using the Microsoft Graph REST. Please replace it with **https://graph.microsoft.com** for the token request to see whether it is helpful. The REST endpoint have to use the corresponding token.

Comment: interesting. Now I recieved a 404 Not found when calling graphServices.getEmails(token);

Comment: Thanks a lot bruh. That was the problem and now things are fixed. I'll provide the full answer here.

Comment: I was now able to get things work somehow. After changing the end points to refer to graph.microsoft.com I was able to get users email for now. But when I tried to access their messages using the following end point (graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@microsoft.com/Messages) I received 403 forbidden exception. Am I missing something ? This end pint > graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users brought me results though.

Comment: Fei Xue - What you said doesn't even make sense. First you say "To authenticate in the daemon or service apps, we can use Client Credentials flow. After we register the app, we would get the secret." Then in the comments you say "FYI, you cant use client secret for Daemon services. You must use a certificate". So what is the correct thing to use?