# 403:forbidden when reading mails from server side application using Microsoft Graph

Tags: java, office365, adal, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm developing a server side application to retrieve emails from our Office 365, filter the emails and store it in our DB without users login. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258408/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-rest-api-in-java) is a link to my previous question if you want to see some details.

I've the following methods

```
@Test
    public void testGetAccessTokenDeamon() throws Exception {

        String tenant="f0245-fd24-r3s-be8a-7745gra60be3";
        String authority = "https://login.windows.net/"+tenant+"/oauth2/authorize";
        ExecutorService service=null;
        service= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        try{

            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext= new AuthenticationContext(authority,false,service);
            String certFile="/mycert.pfx";
            InputStream pkcs12Cert= new SharedFileInputStream(certFile);

            AsymmetricKeyCredential credential=AsymmetricKeyCredential.create("g564f4-e53c-45b7-938a-gt6445gy667",pkcs12Cert,"passwd");


            Future<AuthenticationResult> future=authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com",credential,null);

            System.out.println("Token Received"+future.get().getAccessToken());
            String token = future.get().getAccessToken();

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");

            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);


            GraphServices graphServices = new GraphServices();
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;


            responseEntity = graphServices.getEmails(token);




            //HttpClient httpClient= HttpClients.createDefault();

            //HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            //HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

public ResponseEntity<String> getEmails(String accessToken) throws Exception
    {
        logger.info("In getEmails");

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        HttpEntity<String> request;

        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add(AuthorizationConstants.AUTHORIZATION, AuthorizationConstants.BEARER + " " + accessToken);
        request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/abc@microsoft.com/messages", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        return response;
    }
```

If I try to use **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/** in the restTemplate I will get a list of users but for a specific user the above code returns 403.

Can you please advice me which end points to use so that my app can access individual messages without users login ? I've already gave the app all permissions (delegate and app permissions) that are necessary.

**UPDATE**: This is what I have when I run the token on http://jwt.calebb.net/ and couldn't find the scp/scope section.

```
{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "xxxxx_mfg5JKHrwLBbd_4s",
 kid: "xxxxx_mfg5JKHrwLBbd_4s"
}.
{
 aud: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/f456fyu44-df44-d3t3-f342-66423er4323/",
 iat: 1473280446,
 nbf: 1473280446,
 exp: 1473284346,
 appid: "4fw423gh-er423-45b7-zd32-3fwer2343szd",
 appidacr: "2",
 e_exp: 10800,
 idp: "https://sts.windows.net/g0412253-aeb2-4a8a-ju76-8736272a3u7e3/",
 oid: "33dd3455-0195-4708-rt44-34552321ds32d2",
 sub: "33dd3455-0195-4708-813d-34552321ds32d2",
 tid: "33dd3455-ae23-r456-be8a-7737cf4321d2e3",
 ver: "1.0"
}.
[signature]
```

Here are the permissions I gave (all permissions for now) for the app.

**Microsoft Graph - Application Permissions: 18 -Delegated Permissions: 40
Windows Azure Active Directory -Application Permissions: 4 - Delegated Permissions: 8
Office 365 Exchange Online -Application Permissions: 9- Delegated Permissions: 30**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already gave the app all permissions (delegate and app permissions) that are necessary.

This is probably not the case :). Typically 403 forbidden means your token doesn't have the required scope (in the `scp` claim) for the API you're calling. Easy way to find out: grab the token in the debugger (it's a big long base64 string), then head over to http://jwt.calebb.net/ and paste it in. You'll see it decoded into a JSON web token. Look for the `roles` claim:

```
roles: [
  "Calendars.Read",
  "Mail.Read",
  "Contacts.Read" 
],
```

If you don't have `Mail.Read` or `Mail.ReadWrite`, you don't have the necessary permissions configured.

Comment: There is no scp section at all. :(

Comment: I updated my question to reflect to the current token.

Comment: Where do I configure the scope if it is different from the above ?

Comment: Have you consented to the application? You need to navigate to  - https:// login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&resource={1}&redirect_uri={2}&state=SomeState&prompt=admin_consent

(Make sure you replace {0}, {1} and {2})

Comment: I've given application and delegate permission for the application using Azure management interface.

Comment: Unsupported 'prompt' value when I used prompt=admin_consent

Comment: My bad, it's actually the `roles` claim in an app token. I think you may be having an issue because you define both app and delegate permissions, and I seem to recall that causing a problem. Try removing your delegated permissions and getting a new token.

Comment: @Saca: consent is not needed if he's registered the app in the tenant that he's accessing. Essentially registering = consent. What you're describing is only needed in multitenant scenarios.

Comment: @JasonJohnston I tried removing all delegates and I still don't see roles claim in the token (as I've pasted the result I got from jwt) btw, the token I received is always the same token.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that I've seen caching issues when adding/removing configured permissions on an app registration, so maybe it will clear up and start working. If not, it may be some subtle difference in how the ADAL library is handling the token request. It would be good if you could capture the request/response over the wire. I'll see if we can get one of the ADAL guys to take a look.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Thank you for your reply again. Even though I wasn't able to see the roles, we found out that the person who created the application on Azure AD didn't have full admin access. I guess this lead the application created by this person not to have access to individual emails. Once the user have a full admin access, I was able to fetch the data needed. So we are good for now. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: @JasonJohnston another related question. I made the following GET call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ab@cd.com/messages?$filter=isread%20eq%20false in order to access messages that are unread and I receive 404 not found. Not only this but every time I sent a data using $filter I get the same error. So does $filter works only when you are authenticated by each individual user (for e.g https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$filter=Subject%20eq%20%27Good) ? I am trying to get unread emails for a specific user using a batch job I am building. I appericiate your help.

Comment: It should work. I'd suggest asking another question here for this, the comments are already lengthy :)